# ActionbarSherlock On navigating to new activity home icon change

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As in new action bars, when user clicks on any activity on dashboard, app will take user to new activity, at the same time along with home icon in action bar there would be an arrow showing this activity been started from other activity. How to get this feature with Sherlock android bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> home icon in action bar there would be an arrow showing this activity been started from other activity

That is not what that arrow means. That arrow means that you are giving the user an option of moving "up" a navigation hierarchy, in addition to the BACK button offering navigation back to the preceding activity. This is described in greater detail in [the Android Design documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

> How to get this feature with Sherlock android bar?

The same way you do with the native action bar: call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` on the `ActionBar`.

Comment: Thank you. Understood the difference. It is working now. Correct function is `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: @Srinivas: Sorry, I was writing that from memory. I have updated the answer. Thanks!